# How to check if there's changed Linq2SQL objects before commiting

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I've some classes, for example, Parent and Children. Parent have a collection of Children objects, and I use Linq 2 SQL to persist them. The problem is: if some properties change in the Children object, I may need to update the Parent object, and I need to check it before persisting.

I have a ChildrenRepository with the Insert(Children children) method, that basically calls the InsertOnSubmit(Children children) method from Linq 2 SQL, and the Save() method that calls the SubmitChanges() from Linq 2 SQL. I want to check in the Save() method if there's any Children object that was modified, and if there's, do the work. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have reference to the child object:

```
var changes = context.GetChangeSet();
if (changes.Updates.Contains(yourChildObject))
    // Update Parent
```

else

```
changes.Updates.Where(o => o is Child);
```

Comment: Seems like that's it. +1 I'll accept your answer after test it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

make the parent changes part of the domain logic, that way you can let the data access layer do it's job without requiring your intervention. here is one example

```
var child = parent.Child(...);
child.Update(...);
```

and the logic for Update, assuming a bidirectional relationship.

class Child
   {
      public void Update(...);
      {
          set properties of child;
          Parent.Property = new value;
      }
   }

in this scenario you don't need to worry about the data access internals.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, but I'm working in a framework and I'm afraid some could just get the Child object from the child repository, update some properties and save it in the repository without using my Update method, then I would have a inconsistence... I would like to assure every time someone try to save it, the parent was updated as well.

Comment: so train the developers and make the internal api discoverable. hacking the dal only makes the code base more difficult to understand and doesn't develop the programming team.